# Listview item relative layout background color must match parent height

Tags: android, xml, listview

please help me.

im developing song book application.

but i encounter some problem that i dont know how to do.

please see picture below.

i want the background of my relative to match parent height.

[image]

here is my xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_marginRight="160dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dip">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/framelayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="17dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/framelayout2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/volume"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="right|top" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/artist"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="left|top" />

                </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#eeeeee"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/relativeLayout3">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/mic"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/heart"
                android:layout_gravity="right|top" />

        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#cccccc"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />

        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

i want this RelativeLayout to match the parent height

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#cccccc"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />

        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**CODE UPDATE AND IMAGE**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="80"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:paddingRight="5dip">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_weight="80">
                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/framelayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="17dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </FrameLayout>
                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/framelayout2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/volume"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="right|top" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/artist"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="left|top" />
                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:background="#eeeeee"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/relativeLayout3">
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_weight="10">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/mic"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|top" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/heart"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|top" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:background="#cccccc"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3">
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="10">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/number"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="17dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: So get rid of the `background` attribute.

Comment: what i mean is match the parent height.

Comment: which element's background do you want to be matched ? can you make it clear

Comment: Then edit your title, too.

Comment: Just add `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to your `RelativeLayout` having id `android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"`, it will work.

Comment: please see edit image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingLeft="10dip" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_marginRight="160dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dip">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/framelayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/framelayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/volume"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right|top" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/artist"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#eeeeee"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/relativeLayout3">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/camera"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/camera"
            android:layout_gravity="right|top" />
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#cccccc"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks, just 1 more question. im now getting the problem in the width.. i want to match the width withour setting static width in the first relative. just like the image at the top.

Comment: @Joehamir for that you have used `WeightSum`  and put in  `Linearlayout`. it will part your layout without using any static value.

Comment: please see update. im now getting that result. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#cccccc"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```